# Design tools in Fedora

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, interface-design, android

I am reasonably experience developer on photoshop and it has spoiled me to no extent. I am searching for a graphic tool on fedora which is simple to generate images that I would like to use on my android apps. I have tried my hand with Gimp and it seems to have huge learning curve. Is there any photoshop like app in Fedora which can help ?

Comment: Maybe this is enough for you http://pixlr.com/editor/

Comment: The GIMP pretty much *is* the 'PhotoShop-like app for Linux'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, congratulations on using Fedora, it's amazing.

You can always install plugins for Gimp to imitate certain photoshop behaviours.

Check this article: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/03/8-handy-tweaks-to-make-gimp-replace-photoshop/. You can for example install Layer Styles (Layer Effects GIMP plug-in from Gimp.org), [CMYK Color Separation](http://cue.yellowmagic.info/softwares/separate.html), [Liquid Rescale](http://liquidrescale.wikidot.com/), and [brushes](http://www.blendfu.com/), among others.

Answer (score 2):

The Gimp doesn't have a huge learning curve.

Also, try [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/). My girlfriend uses Inkscape and Gimp (on Debian) and [this](http://hyanna-natsu.deviantart.com/) is what she does with them.